# Playing video via choose file in video js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am using video.js in my reacct application. I want to have a choose file button on the same page and I want to open a video file from local directory in the video player. How can I do it? Can someone please give me a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like in Choose file button, just add:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="onFileChange()" />
```

And then in video.js you set your src

```
this.onFileChange = function () {
  let file = document.getElementById('file');

  let video = videojs("video"); // Ref to your video el
  video.src(file.value);
};
```

Comment: `VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media.`